# Thunderbolt bandwidth monitoring

Tags: monitor, thunderbolt, bandwidth

I'm looking for a tool to monitor the current Thunderbolt bandwidth usage (in Gbits/s).
Is there such a thing? I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Here is a potential solution: https://www.tecmint.com/linux-network-bandwidth-monitoring-tools/

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: @Jeff I'm talking about Thunderbolt, not network.

Comment: @guiverc Well Ubuntu version does not really matters, I'd be happy with a tool running on another version.